# How can you only allow valid paths to a nested object in a template literal type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I basically have 2 objects. Depending on the selected key, I want the second part of my string to be a key of the value of the selected key in the object. In the example, after the `.` in `t("common.")`, only `"test" | "test2"` should be allowed.

```
const common = {
  "test": "Test",
  "test2": "Test2"
}

const greetings = {
  "hello": "Hello"
}

export type I18nMap = Record<typeof locales[number], I18nNamespace>;
export interface I18nNamespace {
    common: typeof common;
    greetings: typeof greetings;
}
export const locales = (["en", "nl"] as const);

type Interpolation = Record<string, string | number>

export function useTranslation<
  T extends keyof I18nNamespace,
  U extends T extends T ? keyof I18nNamespace[T] : never,
  V extends `${T}.${U}`
>(namespace: T | T[]): {t: (key: V, interpolation?: Interpolation) => void} {
  // ...
}

const { t } = useTranslation(["common", "greetings"])

// Only allow common.test | common.test2
t("common.")
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCEB2N0AeMANChpgIYA2VARhQMYDWpa6AsuiBHAL5wAzKBBBwARFHSMYYgFCyGuVPEUhuOOAF5EsuOPzKxALnEAVdIeK79FmACZjZ2w9m95inMrgBzSehjAON6oWjp6YgAW6DQQjmIAEtFUsa7yhJCwcDAAnmDocACSAIwAHDjsFGChAEroilAAJgA8OXkQAnDJDNQWANo4yCC06FAAuqTFZQByFCAWYIzoAHwA3LLp0PCB%20FACi4WlODNzqAsM%20QjWeqrqJq3o7XA3uGt6er7o-oHBd7kPHR8vkFUGs3BtMh4vF0eiFtAAKXpidA4MSkMQ4KhiUZwCghSEwACUa1k90KeBGkCoFACuBqdWgzWUUG%20pCZ3zgAB84AMhiMlmkCBl4AJkDgGDSNGxTFAKJ4qRKmtZTHBCPgcA0Qkx0NlHpMjrN5osrHoAKoqojIjVwZWqy0hZUAfjgWp1HT1x0N516pmxJhw6AAbiNjXAAGrmtVWgAGABIEKZeAA6OMm3hR2RLOE4A2nRYmZVc0y9UYEsJwAD05bgAAEYKgALTAbw4aDoaz4p64fBEUJsbDkohw4CHfvdwnEvTADpwgCEHjHpcubyyEWEAHc4ABRKDCKBwsRSmVy6nAWkRCAQJhwEBoeDDJ7UKjoBpwNfAGARQIHMoABWEAeABoRkTMQiWsNx2yUeB4G0PtH3oZg4SuOA4RdExQ1IbYKQgeVTxwB0TAKckoEpE9cFLTQlh0ZDeBDPR%20hzM50FIedVVGawwOsSsazrRtm1baxJBgZAoElDBOG4OE4Qoqi4SQEhOggbonxMViiETaEnz4AlSF6NSFOzE4mJLUF3CgxAsj4XsMGlWVUFw3AETEZ4UTRQEAmBLECXkbiAHkMWyHEYg3FzEwMeAuVC8K7BJfdQtAoA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this type:

```
type GetI18nKeys<T extends keyof I18nNamespace> = T extends unknown
  ? `${T}.${Extract<keyof I18nNamespace[T], string>}`
  : never;
```

This distributes `T` and makes a string type based on `T` and `keyof I18nNamespace[T]`. Without the `Extract<..., string>`, TypeScript would complain because property keys can be a `symbol`, which is not assignable to the types that can be in a template literal (`string | number | bigint | boolean`).

You also don't need the `U` and `V` type parameters in this situation.

```
export function useTranslation<T extends keyof I18nNamespace>(
  namespace: T | T[]
): {t: (key: GetI18nKeys<T>, interpolation?: Interpolation) => void} {
  // ...
}

const { t } = useTranslation(["common", "greetings"])

// Works
t('common.test')
t('common.test2')
t('greetings.hello')

// Fails
t('common.hello')
t('greetngs.test')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#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-7ziZpRzTL1RniwnAAPSduAAARgqAAtMBvEbJFclCpcPgiKE2NhSUQYcBDguZ-jCXpgB0YQBCDzr9uXPR6GARYTGuDOqDCKAwsRZnOoPPAakRCAQJhwEBoeDDR7UFQ6ANHAxrAGegQHGUAAKwixsADQjA6YgEtYbgTp48DwNo86AfQzAwtYegwl6JiCjAwpihKUpLKQ2xkhAL64GaJgFKSUDkpSr44O2miapcRF8FYJ5wP0dZnOgpAHrKozWKh1jdn2A7DqO0DoNYkgwMgUCZhgnDcDCMK8ZqMJICQnQQN0QEmNJRAOpCQF8HipC9LZ5m1icEltsC7iTogWR8HOGDZhQuZcbgcJiE8SIov8ASAhieLyIpADq0BMKgRIwgA5NFDoGDA2VJTAOV5QVdhFVl2VxZ8qAOlEMSVbIikAGIUMAVCZSVuUiOo9VJBAlXdXFgL5bYlVAA)